# Yoneda Ext theorem and extensions

Tags: ct.category-theory, homological-algebra, triangulated-categories, extension

Consider the category of chain complexes over a ring $R$.

We can show that $\text{Ext}^1(M, N)$ classifies extensions using the triangulated category structure: the homotopy kernel of a map $N \rightarrow M[1]$, $K$, gives rise to the designated triangle $M \rightarrow K \rightarrow N$. This gives a simple picture of Yoneda's extension theorem for $\text{Ext}^1(M, N)$, which also seems to rely on the "threeness" of a triangulated category.

My question is, is there an extension of this view to $\text{Ext}^n(M, N)$?

The proof of the situation for $\text{Ext}^1$ is quite simple using triangulated categories and it would be nice if the situation could be handled the same way for $\text{Ext}^n$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We have that $\mathrm{Ext}^n(M, N) = \mathrm{Hom}(M, N[n])$, in other words, an element of $\mathrm{Ext}^n(M, N)$ is a map
$$
M \longrightarrow I_N[n]
$$
where $N \to I_N$ is an injective resolution. From this we obtain a distinguished triangle,
$$
M \longrightarrow I_N[n] \longrightarrow C \overset{+}\longrightarrow
$$
The homotopical invariant gives an extension of complexes
$$
0 \longrightarrow I_N[n] \longrightarrow C \longrightarrow M \longrightarrow 0 \
$$
which, plugin-in the beginning of the resolution of $N$, yields the classical $n$-extension
$$
0 \longrightarrow N \longrightarrow I^0_N \longrightarrow I^1_N \cdots  \longrightarrow I^{n-1}_N \longrightarrow M \longrightarrow 0
$$
as wanted

Comment: Out of curiosity: I think the theorem for $\textrm{Ext}^1$ can be proved without assuming enough injectives. The OP asks about modules over a ring but we could equally ask about any abelian category.

Comment: Sorry for not getting it yet, but how do the injective extensions correspond to ordinary ones?

Comment: @ZhenLin Of course,  I was answering the case in the question. As a matter of fact, my argument work whenever the base category is Grothendieck. In general it is not clear to me that Ext and Yoneda-Ext agree

Comment: @KindBubble It is because injective resolutions are universal up to homotopy.

Comment: @LeoAlonso what is the equivalence relation on extensions? Is it weak equivalence?

Comment: @KindBubble Basically, there is a collection of isomorphism commuting with the identities of $N$ and $M$ (and among themselves). For more details see, for instance, Maclana, Homology, chapter III, §8, p. 96.

Comment: @LeoAlonso Thanks. I think I got it from your comment after all.

Comment: There are actually $n+1$ elements in between  $M$ and $N$, this is an $ n+1$ extension, isn't it?

Comment: @L.Xie Indeed, it was a typo. The derived category perspective makes things easier, though.

Comment: @LeoAlonso An element in $Ext^n(M,N)$ corresponds to an $n$-extension that starts with $N$ and ends with $M$, right? Why is your extension starting with $M$ and ending with $N$?

Comment: @L.Xie Hope that with this edit, things a re a little bit more explicit.